# OperationalError: no such table: alguém pode me ajudar?

Tags: python

Estou tentando ler um arquivo do sqlite no Jupyter Notebook, entretanto aparece esse erro : OperationalError: no such table:
alguém pode me ajudar?

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('escola.sqlite')
c = conn.cursor()

def leitura_todos_dados():
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM escola")
    for linha in c.fetchall():
        print(linha)

leitura_todos_dados()
```

> OperationalError        Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>   ----> 1 leitura_todos_dados()
>         2
>
> in leitura_todos_dados()
>        10 
>        11 def leitura_todos_dados():
>   ---> 12     c.execute("SELECT * FROM escola")
>        13     for linha in c.fetchall():
>        14         print(linha)
>
> OperationalError: no such table: escola

Comment: Pelo visto não existe a tabela "escola" no banco de dados.

Comment: O colega Anderson tem razão. A mensagem de erro é bem clara: não existe uma tabela chamada "escola" no seu banco de dados.

Comment: Você já criou as tabelas e deu os inserts para capturar os dados?

Comment: Olá desculpem, quando gerei a tabela no banco de dados ele criou somente o banco e não transferiu a tabela com os dados. Eu tinha um arquivo csv e quando "transferi" os dados para o db parte dos dados não estava migrando, quando resolvi isso deu certo. Obrigada!

Comment: A mensagem está indicando que a tabela escola não existe. Confira seu banco de dados e veja se ela existe mesmo.